# Can't show 3 kinds of color in a Text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to make a label using SwiftUI showing text in 3 colors i.e. ABC (A in black, B in gray, C in red) by following code

```
let aString = "A"
let bString = "B"
let cString = "C"

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(aString)\(Text(bString).foregroundColor(Color.gray))\(Text(cString).foregroundColor(Color.red))")
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

But the result is
[image]

The last text `1` is unexpected.

The iOS project is for iOS 14
I run the app at iPad Pro 11-inch 2nd gen, iPadOS 14.1

Comment: it seems that swift/swiftui is confused by the string interpolations.
All works well if you put a space between the elements. Where does the "1" comes from ... swiftui magic?

Comment: I would better not use that approach, since it is not very clean

Comment: You can use the SwiftUI’s text view  + operator so that you can combine text views together to make new text views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean and clear approach that still produce the expected result would be:

```
Text(aString).foregroundColor(.black)
+  Text(bString).foregroundColor(.gray)
+  Text(cString).foregroundColor(.red)
```